# how to update item in a list of array in other components

Tags: reactjs

I am building a Todo App using Redux. I only build **create** and **delete**.

I want to build an `<Edit />` which todo's message will appear/edit in `<TodoForm />`.

How can I do this ?

```
<>
  <TodoForm />
  <TodoList />
</>
```

I think I am going to move local state (useState) to global state (redux).

Is there any tips to apply, please suggest

*P.S. Most of the tutorial on the Internet just cover a simple **add**, **delete** todo's task but it's not cover **edit**. That's what I want*

My codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-darkness-miibs

Comment: what you've tried so far ?

Comment: I have created a sample app using react context API to manage global scope, check this 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management

Answer (score 0):

There's not much we can get with the info you've provided above. Anyway, I just guessing here:-

- right now you have all your **form** `state` declared as the **local** `state` inside your `TodoForm` component.
- you only have **one global** `state` to hold all the todo list. Preferably in an `array`

I would suggest just:-

- **create** a new **local** `state` in component `TodoForm` that can do the **edit** functionality that you want. (ex: `const[isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false)`)
- **create** a `function` to run the **event of editing** (of course this event should reflect/update your **global** `state` `array` of **todo** list)
- **create** a `button` to run **above event** and **change** `isEdit` `state` from `false` to `true` (we use this to give the ability to cancel editing). Upon **edit** button **clicked**, update/populate all `input` fields with the **current** data you wish to **edit** (if you want to cancel editing, then **create** a cancel button that will only appeared when `isEdit` `state` is **equals** to `true`. If **clicked**, then reset back `isEdit` `state` to `false` and **unpopulate** current data from all `input` placeholders)